# Inactive required fields and Firefox issue

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, firefox, show-hide

Using jQuery on a dropdown to show/hide text input fields according with the dropdown selection causes a weird behavior in Firefox, not allowing to submit the form until ALL "required" fields are filled, even if these required fields are hidden based on the selection from the dropdown, or so to say, they are in fact inactive.

Safari, just ignores the non visible "required" fields and only checks for the active (visible) required fields, and if these are filled, the form is good to be submitted.

I've tried to search around for any occurrences and possible solutions for this but seem to find none.

Example:

```
<select id="theselect" name="something">
    <option value="1" selected>One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="one" required="required" class="show" />
<input type="text" name="two" required="" class="hide" />
<input type="text" name="three" required="required" class="hide" />
```

On the above example, having in mind that inputs two and three are hidden, but required if the the select changes to 2 or 3, which will change the state/visibility of the respective input, Firefox forces all the required to be filled.

Has anyone experienced this and / or has some idea of how to manage this effectively with jQuery?
Thanks in advance for any thoughts and help on this.

Comment: use `prop()` method to toggle `required` at same time you toggle the display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even fields that are "hidden" submit.  So if they're flagged as "required", they will cause a validation failure.  The spec is very clear about this.

You probably want to either set them as not required or set them as disabled when you hide them, depending on whether you actually want them to submit in their not-set state.

Comment: Thanks Boris, and yes, in fact that's the approach, but this is, as far as I could test, a Firefox specific issue. Ok, for cross-browser compatibility, have to change their attr and set them as not required.

Comment: If this is Firefox-specific that means other browsers are not doing what the spec says to do.  :(

Comment: Well, at least Safari on Mac, ignores anything that is hidden, while validating the fields, although, I found that the issue I'm dealing with is quite off the browser scope (although what I mentioned is true, regarding browser behavior). I found that this is quite more complex due to mootools validate.js that imposes aria-invalid, aria-required and required="required" if it finds an required css class in the field. Now using the above mentioned methods to remove or add the required properties becomes just a haystack of conditions that is probably better to disable validate.js.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like Safari is implementing a very early spec draft, not what the spec says now.